# /home folder empty after restart

Tags: login, home-directory

After reinstalling some packages I can't access my account. Using recover mode I can ls the /home folder and It is empty. But, after running fsck I can see my folder /home/[MY NAME] and can also ls the content of my home folder. Afterwards, I tried to restart and is empty again so I cannot log in.

Edit 1: I have created another user just to test and it happens the same thing.

Edit 2: I don't know if It is related but during packaged installation I issued then following commands.
$mkdir /home/[MY NAME]/PENDRIVE
$mount /dev/sde1 /home/[MY NAME]/PENDRIVE

Comment: Is your `/home` mounted from other disk partition than `/` ? You can check it for eg by `cat /etc/fstab`

Comment: There is no mounting point for my home!

Comment: Its shows:
"/home was on /dev/sda6 during installation"
UUID=ee116a3b-266... /home

Answer (score 1):

It looks like one of your partitions contains file system errors.

Luckily you can still use your booted system to try to repair it.
Run [the tool that helps to fix the errors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fsck):

> fsck /dev/sda6

After that, you can remount your home by:

> mount /dev/sda6

If it mounts with no more errors or warnings, it should remount again after reboot too.

Comment: I have done the described commands and got no errors. After that I can login using terminal, but cannot do it using GUI.

Comment: What does `mount /dev/sda6` returns?

Comment: After mounting, I  issued
$exit
And then I chose resume. Then I tried to login using GUI but no luck. 
Then I tried to login using virtual console "ctrl + ctrl + 1". I was successful. So, I decided to back to GUI (alt+f7) and try again, but no luck.

Comment: Did `fsck` fixed the partition? Do you see any directories in `/home`? Did you lost any important files? Is it mounted for sure - do you see it listed on `mount` command?

Comment: Yes It fixed. Yes I see my home inside /home. I did not loose any file. It is mounted for sure. Yes.
But after a restarting the problem appears again.

Comment: It is working now. I changed the password after using your steps! Thank you very much!